# Need Help Regarding Selecting Image in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to allow the app user to select an image from their gallery and only set the image uri if the user actually selects it. The problem I'm facing is that when I open the gallery of images all of the images are grayed out and I cannot select an image regardless of the image format. Here is my code:

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView edtsdate, edtbirthdate;
    int date, month, year;
    EditText emailEditText, passEditText, conpassEditText, userEditText, edtAddress, edtcontact;
    RadioGroup gender;
    ImageView userphoto;
    static int PReqCode =1;
    static int REQUESCODE =1;
    Uri pickedImg;
    private EditText edtfn;
    private EditText edtLn;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // Write a message to the database
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("User");
        /*FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);*/
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_register1);
        edtsdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.birthdate);
        edtsdate.setOnClickListener(this);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        gender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogrp);
        edtfn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Fname);
        edtLn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        edtbirthdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.birthdate);
        edtcontact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Contact);
        emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
        passEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
        conpassEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Confirm);
        userEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        edtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        userphoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
        userphoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22) {
                    checkAndRequestForPermission();
                }
                else
                    {
                    openGallery();
                }

            }
        });

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // final String gend = gender.
                final String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
                final String pass = passEditText.getText().toString();
                final String confirm = conpassEditText.getText().toString();
                final String username = userEditText.getText().toString();
                final String strfn = edtfn.getText().toString();
                final String strln = edtLn.getText().toString();
                final String edtadd = edtAddress.getText().toString();
                final String birth = edtbirthdate.getText().toString();
                final String mobile = edtcontact.getText().toString();
                final String bdate = edtbirthdate.getText().toString();
                if (email.equals("") && email.isEmpty()) {

                    emailEditText.setError("Enter  Email");

                } else if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
                    emailEditText.setError("Invalid Email");
                } else if (pass.equals("") && pass.isEmpty()) {

                    passEditText.setError("Enter Password");

                } else if (!isValidPassword(pass)) {
                    passEditText.setError("Please Use Combination of Upper Case(A-Z),Lower Case(a-z),and Numbers(0-9) and should be of minimum 6 character ");

                } else if (!pass.contentEquals(confirm)) {
                    conpassEditText.setError("Password Not Match");
                } else if (username.equals("")) {
                    userEditText.setError("Username Can't be Empty");
                } else if (mobile.equals("*")) {
                    edtcontact.setError("Enter Valid Mobile Number");
                } else {
                       /* CreateUserAccount(email,confirm,strfn,strln,username,mobile,bdate,edtadd,pass);*/
                    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(Signup.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                final String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
                                final String pass = passEditText.getText().toString();
                                final String confirm = conpassEditText.getText().toString();
                                final String username = userEditText.getText().toString();
                                final String strfn = edtfn.getText().toString();
                                final String strln = edtLn.getText().toString();
                                final String edtadd = edtAddress.getText().toString();
                                final String birth = edtbirthdate.getText().toString();
                                final String mobile = edtcontact.getText().toString();
                                final String bdate = edtbirthdate.getText().toString();
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                        Log.d("TAG", "createUserWithEmail:success");
                                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                        String strUserID = user.getUid();

                                        String userkey = myRef.push().getKey();
                                        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
                                        userModel.setFirstname(strfn);
                                        userModel.setLastname(strln);
                                        userModel.setEmailid(email);
                                        userModel.setPassword(confirm);
                                        userModel.setUsername(username);
                                        userModel.setUserid(strUserID);
                                        userModel.setSignaddress(edtadd);

                                        userModel.setMobileno(mobile);
                                        userModel.setUser_birthdate(bdate);
                                        myRef.child(strUserID).setValue(userModel);


                                        updateUserInfo(username,pickedImg,mAuth.getCurrentUser());

                                        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Sign Up Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                        Intent i = new Intent(Signup.this, Login.class);
                                        startActivity(i);

                                    } else {
                                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                        Log.w("TAG ", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        //updateUI(null);
                                    }

                                    // ...
                                }
                            });

                }

            }
        });
    }


  /*  private void CreateUserAccount(String pass, final String email, final String confirm, final String strfn, final String strln, final String username, final String mobile, final String bdate, final String edtadd) {




    }*/

    private void updateUserInfo(final String username, Uri pickedImg, final FirebaseUser currentUser) {

        StorageReference mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("users_photos");
        final StorageReference imageFilePath = mStorage.child(pickedImg.getLastPathSegment());
        imageFilePath.putFile(pickedImg).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                imageFilePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setDisplayName(username)
                                .setPhotoUri(uri)
                                .build();

                        currentUser.updateProfile(profileUpdate)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                            Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Photo Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            updateUI();


                                        }

                                    }
                                });


                    }
                });


            }
        });



    }

    private void showMessage(String registered_successfully) {


        Toast.makeText(this, registered_successfully, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void openGallery() {

        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       /* Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);*/
        gallery.setType("images/*");
        startActivityForResult(gallery,REQUESCODE);




    }

    private void checkAndRequestForPermission() {

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Signup.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Signup.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Please Accept For Required Permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Signup.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                                    PReqCode);
            }

        }
        else
            openGallery();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUESCODE && data !=null){
           pickedImg = data.getData();
           userphoto.setImageURI(pickedImg);




        }




    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Sign Up Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*Intent i = new Intent(Signup.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.birthdate:
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        edtsdate.setText(i2 + "/" + (i1 + 1) + "/" + i);
                    }
                }, year, month, date);

                datePickerDialog.show();
                break;
        }
    }


    // validating email id
    private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    // validating password with retype password
    private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
        if (pass != null && pass.length() > 6) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Image Pick

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO);
```

override OnActivityResult()

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                //Display an error
                return;
            }
            try {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                Log.e("TAG", "file path => " + selectedImagePath);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

get path from uri

```
/**
     * helper to retrieve the path of an image URI
     */
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        // just some safety built in
        if (uri == null) {
            // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
            return null;
        }
        // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
        // this will only work for images selected from gallery
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String path = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
            return path;
        }
        // this is our fallback here
        return uri.getPath();
    }
```

hope it helps.